# Open AppServices connection from UWP to Win32

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-navigation

I've been working with AppServices. I know that I can open a connection from a Win32 process to a UWP. But I need it the other way around.
Is it possible to open a AppServices connection from a UWP -> Win32?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not try it? [Sample here](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/tree/master/UWP_FullTrust_3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to open a AppServices connection from a UWP -> Win32?

No. First, you can't register the appservice in your win32 application. And you can't handle the connection request in the win32 app as well because it requires BackgroundActivated event.